# add css and jquery to custom page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am Using wordpress.org. I have created a custom page with index file and references to css and javascript file is included in the index file . but how to add those multiple css and javascript files in wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, have a look at [wp_enqueue_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function.

Following code, inserted into your **theme's functions.php**, will load your custom_script.js from your theme's js directory (this script depends on jquery):

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

To load stylesheet, use the same hook, but with wp_enqueue_style function:

```
function my_styles_method() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_style.css'
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_method');
```

Or you can merge these two calls into one:

```
function my_scripts_and_styles_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'custom-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_style.css'
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_and_styles_method');
```

It also would't be wrong to [wp_register_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) before enqueuing it, but is not obligatory

Comment: thank you but how to add multiple scipts,this is just for 1 js and 1 css script but i want it for 4 js scripts and 3 css scripts.

Comment: Duplicate wp_enqueue_style/wp_enqueue_script with modified path and script/style slug: wp_enqueue_style('custom-script-1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_style_2.css' );wp_enqueue_style('custom-script-2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom_style_2.css' ); ...